# "Could not load the kernel" when starting the camera session and trying to do some live image filtering

Tags: iphone, ios, image-processing, opengl-es

I'm trying to do some live image filtering like what Instagram and Path does. I heavily implemented this method:

```
-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {
```

I used the camera session and the CoreImage framework (I didn't use OpenGL directly). Most of the times, my app would run pretty happily without crash or hiccup.

However, when I try to start the live filtering camera session when my app is undergoing some **UIView** animation on the screen. I would see a black screen on the live filtering area. Besides, the console would print repeatedly some thing like this:

> Invalid shader program, probably due to exceeding hardware resources

And:

> Could not load the kernel!

When such error occurs, I observed that I could fix it by simply re-init and re-start my camera session. Therefore, as long as my code would be notified in the run-time, I could easily fix the situation simply by letting the code do a run-time check and if such situation occurs, re-start the camera session.

But there is one big problem, when such errors occurs, my code won't be notified. There's no call back, there's no crash, there's no exception, there's no strange nil pointer.

Anyone could help?

Answer (score 0):

The "kernel" in question is not the iOS kernel, but an OpenCL kernel. It occurs in the OpenCL.framework (public in OS X, but private in iOS, available as of iOS 5). Since it's private, you're very likely stuck here. Initializing OpenCL does take a considerable chunk of system resources. A good approach is to mutually exclude (mutex) access to the screen by holding it when you are in UIView animations.

Hope this helps,

TG